# Show that $D_2\cong C_2\times C_2$

Tags: group-theory

I've started by determining two representations for the cyclic group $C_2$, being one of them the identity representation (1 1) and the second one the orthogonal "vector" (1 -1). How do I show that $D_2\cong C_2 \times C_2$ using those two representations?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of $D_2$?

Answer (score 2):

The dihedral group $D_n$ can be defined geometrically, which is usually for $n\ge 3$ because we want a non-trivial $n$-gon, or algebraically for all $n \ge 1$ by
$$
D_n=\langle r,s \mid r^n=s^2=1, srs=r^{-1}\rangle
$$

For $n=2$ we have $r^2=1$ so that $r^{-1}=r$ and thus
$$
D_2=\langle r,s \mid r^2=s^2=1, sr=rs\rangle \cong C_2 \times C_2.
$$

References:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group)

[Notes by K. Conrad](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi40fG9n4DnAhVBYVAKHTGrCsUQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkconrad.math.uconn.edu%2Fblurbs%2Fgrouptheory%2Fdihedral.pdf&usg=AOvVaw36MGK7uiNhk1IurvhdABG-)

[Precise definition of Dihedral Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717025/precise-definition-of-dihedral-group)

Comment: The last line explicits the definition of $D_2$ to immediately establish the isomorphism. Is it so straightforward or can it be made more explicit in turn?

Comment: It is explained, for example, at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group), see "Presentations".